# Есть два callback ,как с помощью промиса реализовать их в синхронный код?

Tags: javascript, callback, асинхронность, promise

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        var userCity = data.city;


});
```

**Здесь получаю данные о городе**

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://****.ru/api/app.getProductInCity?city='+CITY+"&art="+ID);
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

    var url = "https://****.ru"+data.URL+"/";
    var dateDelivery = data.DATE;
    var priceProduct = data.PRICE;
    var percentDelivery = data.PRICE_DELIVERY;



}
ourRequest.send();
```

**Здесь отправляю запрос на сервер где в переменную CITY уже нужно передать город пользователя, но так как выполнение происходит асинхронно туда ничего не приходит.
Как с помощью промисов можно решить эту проблему?**

Comment: Раз вы используете JQuery, так почему не везде? Ведь это гораздо всё упростит

Comment: Я уже думал об этом, но это не главная проблема

Comment: А где объявляется переменная `CITY`?

Comment: Это как пример было использованно. Туда надо передать то что вернет первый callback

Comment: Вы можете второй блок кода завернуть в callback первого или в создать функцию из второго блока и вызывать её в callback первого

Comment: Не может быть такого что ответ от первого еще не придет , но вложенный уже выполнится?

Comment: Не может, могу более простой код на JQuery написать для вас

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f06g99hg/ На случай если вам надо строго промис

Comment: Дмитрий, если можно, напишите более простой вариант

Comment: @Дмитрий , если можно, напишите более простой вариант

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/59omr5vx/

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Всё до ужаса просто (https://jsfiddle.net/59omr5vx/):

```
// (data) => { ... } эквивалентно function(data) { ... }
$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', (ip_data) => {
    var CITY = ipdata.city;
  $.getJSON('https://****.ru/api/app.getProductInCity?city='+CITY+'&art='+ID, (product_data) => {
    var url = "https://****.ru"+product_data.URL+"/";
    var dateDelivery = product_data.DATE;
    var priceProduct = product_data.PRICE;
    var percentDelivery = product_data.PRICE_DELIVERY;
  })
});
```

Вариант с промисами, если callback не вариант (https://jsfiddle.net/f06g99hg/):

```
var json_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Симуляция ассинхронность getJson
    document.write('JSON получен<br>');
    resolve("json_done");
  }, 3000);
});

document.write('Скоро будет XHR запрос<br>');
json_promise.then((result) => {
    document.write('JSON вернул ' + result + '<br>');
    // Тут запрос
});
```

Comment: jquery функции так же возвращают Promise-like объект

Comment: Дело не в этом. Просто я не совсем понял, что он хочет, поэтому написал и JQuery, и использование promise.

Comment: а я имел ввиду, что ты мог те же then использовать и для jquery

Comment: Это я знаю, но посмотрите на первый блок его кода и на второй. Вы сразу поймёте, что ему нужно? Я - нет. :)